# "Клондайк". Нужны ли кавычки? Прописная или строчная?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, прописная-строчная, кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли тут кавычки: "Для них там был настоящий клондайк"? И еще — со строчной или прописной нужно писать "клондайк"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо писать со строчной буквы и лучше заключить в кавычки. Строчная буква означает, что значение переносное (богатое место). А кавычки означают, что слово еще окончательно не закреплено в словарях и поэтому его переносное (условное) значение нужно обозначить.

ОТВЕТ 2.Вот похожее решение (ответ на вопрос по поводу "зебры").

С "зеброй" можно поступить двояко: оставить в кавычках (так обычно и делают авторы публицистических текстов), поскольку наименование имеет разговорный оттенок, не является официальным, а с другой стороны – название это уже стало обиходным, широко известным, следовательно, есть основания не выделять его при помощи кавычек. Главное – чтобы было понятно, о какой зебре речь идет речь. 
Мне кажется, что "клондайк" также еще не стало официальным наименованием, в большинстве словарей оно отсутствует.

ОТВЕТ 3. НЕМНОГО ПОДРОБНЕЕ НА ЭТУ ТЕМУ.

1. Пока слово не включено в словарь как нарицательное,  оно должно писаться с прописной буквы. Но оно употребляется в условном значении – следовательно, должно иметь кавычки. Получается, что официально это  «Клондайк».
2. Если  всё-таки считать, что это слово уже нарицательное (не дожидаясь словарей), то оно должно писаться со строчной буквы и без кавычек – клондайк.
3. Форму «клондайк» можно использовать, если считать это слово  нарицательным, но еще непривычным, малоупотребительным.
   Соответственно, в текстах можно встретить все три формы:

Это был настоящий «клондайк». !!! Кипр заселен 10 000 лет, и это настоящий клондайк для любителей древних памятников. Что такое клондайк? Это слово, частенько употребляют, когда говорят о каком-то очень выгодном явлении, предприятии или затее. Нынче, социальные сети – это настоящий «Клондайк*» для грабителей, вымогателей и мошенников.

Comment: Кстати, это же самое с застежкой-молнией. Я вижу и в кавычках, и без них

Comment: Почему же не дожидаясь? У Ефремовой есть, у Лопатина есть, даже в словаре исторических терминов (1998 год!) с указанием и переносного значения тоже.

Answer (score 9):

Слово есть в толковом словаре Ефремовой: Клонда́йк. М. Источник высокой прибыли, больших доходов. Считаю, что кавычки не нужны. С ними слово приобретает как бы обратное ,ироничное звучание. Особенно рядом со словом "настоящий"

Comment: Так  может  оно  и  в  самом  деле  ироничное ?

Comment: Нет, здесь иронией и не пахнет. 
Обычный случай перехода имени собственного в категорию нарицательных. (Не помню вумный термин, может подскажут).